# https:// css background size is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the below html code to view a webpage.  As long as the webpage is viewed from http or a ftp folder path the code works. But the movement I use it from a https:// path it stops working. SharePoint site is used to launch the webpage as https:// site.

Note that the entire page and all its components works except for this particular line of code `document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();

    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var minute = new Date().getMinutes(); 
    var greeting;
    if (( hour == 9 || hour == 11 || hour == 13 || hour == 15 || hour == 17 ) && ( minute <= 20 )) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('file://ourfolder/Images/Image_MFR.jpeg')";
        document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed"; 
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";   
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('file://ourfolder/Images/Image_ICG1.jpeg')";
        document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
    }
}
</script>

<meta http-equiv='refresh' content="60;  url='file://otshare.eur.citi.net@SSL/DavWWWRoot/sites/GIDABPR/CSSBPR/RICA/Chennai/RICA_CH.html' "/>

</body>
</html>
```

Did a lot of research and checked a lot of site, since I am using notepad to build these webpages I was not able to get much help.

Comment: This is because you're using `file://` URLs. Those aren't sent via HTTPS, so you're going to get security warnings if you do that even if the HTML page itself is served over HTTPS.

Comment: Notepad? Are you trying to make it as difficult as you can? Why aren’t you using a better editor? If you’re into Microsoft, you could try Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Agree with @MattBrowne, not sure about share point but try to retrieve the the file through https.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why load these pages this way? It appears you're trying to load different background images every hour at half past the hour. Why not use a server side language to do this, or have this done in a way that doesn't need you to load via the `file://` or use javascript.

Comment: Since you’re setting the background attachment and size to the same both times, have you tried just putting them straight into a `style` block. It least that may help simplify the process.

Comment: Team,  Thanks for all your comments.  My network has set a ton of limitations and due to that all I can use for now to create webpages in a notepad.  I understand the challenges.  as of now all the code lines work when I open this file via https link that is given by SharePoint site expect for the image size.  If this is solved my issue is resolved.

Comment: @Manngo  I am new to this so can you help me with a sample code I can try.

Comment: @Manngo for style block.

Comment: In your `<head>` element, add the following: `<style>body { background-attachment:fixed; background-size: 100% 100%;</style>` }. I can’t add new lines in a comment, so you’ll have to put them in, though it will work as a single line. After that, you can remove two lines from each of the `if` and `else` blocks. That may not solve your problem, but it will be easier to study.